# Velocity of a liquid jet, coming out of a container

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, pressure, velocity

Think of a container which has a hole beneath it. And we have filled the container in height $h$ with a liquid of density $\rho$ and cross section of the hole $a$. (look at the pic)
[image]

Then what is the velocity of the liquid jet coming out of that hole??

Comment: What do you think it is? Why? If you can't show that you have done some work on your own, you will get downvoted and probably closed.

Comment: what are you saying??

Comment: I've asked a question to get an aswer

Comment: You have specifically identified this as a "homework and exercises" question. It is not the policy of folks on this site to do your homework for you.

Comment: OK, I removed that tag. Now if you can, please answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is extremely complicated. To begin with, you have not specified either the viscosity of the liquid, its' compressibility, the diameter of the tank, or the shape of the orfice. All of them count. For instance, if the area of the hole is equal to the area of the tank, there will be no constraint (for low velocities) on the fluid flow, and it will free-fall out of the tank.

But let's make some assumptions.

1) The fluid is incompressible.
2) The bottom of the tank is "thin".
3) Flow rates are always low enough that there is no drag on the walls of the tank.
4) The hole is circular, and centered on the axis of the tank.
5) The viscosity is $\rho $, and is constant.
6) Flow rates are low enough the that there is no back pressure on the exiting fluid due to atmospheric effects.

Then a commonly-used formula (Reader-Harris/Gallagher equation) provides a volume flow rate:

$$q_{v}={\frac {q_{m}}{\rho}}$$
where the mass flow rate

$$q_{m}={\frac {C}{\sqrt {1-\beta ^{4}}}}\;{\frac {\pi }{4}}\;d^{2}\;{\sqrt {2\;\rho _{1} p;}} $$ and C is the Coefficient of Discharge
$$C=0.5961+0.0261\beta ^{2}-0.216\beta ^{8}+0.000521{\bigg (}{\frac {10^{6}\beta }{Re_{D}}}{\bigg )}^{0.7}+(0.0188+0.0063A)\beta ^{3.5}{\bigg (}{\frac {10^{6}}{Re_{D}}}{\bigg )}^{0.3}+(0.043+0.080e^{-10{L_{1}}}-0.123e^{-7{L_{1}}})(1-0.11A){\frac {\beta ^{4}}{1-\beta ^{4}}}-0.031(M'_{2}-0.8{M'_{2}}^{1.1})\beta ^{1.3}$$

and if $D < 71.2mm$ in which case this further term is added to C:$$+0.011(0.75-\beta ){\bigg (}2.8-{\frac {D}{0.025.4}}{\bigg )}$$ In the equation for C, $$A={\bigg (}{\frac {19000\beta }{Re_{D}}}{\bigg )}^{0.8}M'_{2}={\frac {2L'_{2}}{1-\beta }}$$

where:

C
= coefficient of discharge, dimensionless

d
= internal orifice diameter under operating conditions, m

D
= internal pipe diameter under operating conditions, m

p
= fluid absolute static pressure $\rho$ gh, Pa

$q_{m}$
= mass flow rate, kg/s

$q_{v}$
= volume flow rate, m3/s

$Re_{D}$
= pipe Reynolds number, ${\frac {4q_{m}}{\pi \mu D}}$, dimensionless

$\beta$ 
= diameter ratio of orifice diameter to pipe diameter, ${\frac {d}{D}}$, dimensionless

$\mu$ 
= dynamic viscosity of the fluid, Pa.s

So the average velocity of the exiting liquid will be $$V = \frac{q_m}{A}$$

Also note that computation of the velocity will be "a bit" complicated by the fact that the fluid Reynolds number depends on the velocity, and for a large orfice the velocity of the fluid will not be constant over the orfice (viscosity will slow it down at the edges).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

If you can do a lot of simplifications, you can calculate with $A$ crosssection, $dh$ height water "segments", which are accelerated in the outgoing flow on a $dh$ long way, with the water hydrostatic pressure in $h$ deep.

So, the volume of a segment of water: $V=A\cdot dh$

Its mass: $m=\rho V=A\cdot dh \cdot \rho$

The pressure in $h$ deepness: $P=m\cdot h\cdot g$

Its force in $A$ area: $F=P\cdot A=m\cdot h\cdot g\cdot A$.

...and so on. High school physics. Maybe elementary.

In the result $A$ and $\rho$ will fall out.

Answer (score 0):

As usual with beautiful problems, you can explain very elegantly why the right answer is right; unfortunately one only too seldom actually finds the answers this way, it's always in retrospect that it's elegant :)

Of course I do not mean the real-world-problem with viscose water, as @WhatRoughBeast has tried to approach. Instead (since it was a homework) the simplified problem @peterh is referring to. Dry water, as Feynman calls it.

So, you can do the calculations like @peterh stated; basically: apply mass conservation and energy conservation. The solution will be: the velocity is as large, as if the water particles were falling from the height of the surface, i.e. $\sqrt{2gh}$.
If the water flowing out is the same amount as what is reduced near the upper surface, this velocity satisfies energy conservation: the potential energy per mass decreases exactly according to this height.

Very beautiful; a shame, I didn't find it before reading Feynman :)